# How do I upload my zipped lambda code into AWS Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

So I've read through the docs at: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html

I've created the zip file, how / where do I actually upload / publish this zip file into AWS?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's kind of hidden away and not very intuitive.

Within the AWS Lamba admin: Create Function > Author from Scratch.
Within the `Code entry type` dropdown there is a `Upload a .ZIP file` option.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can upload using aws-cli.

```
aws configure

aws lambda list-functions

aws lambda update-function-code \
    --function-name MyLambdaFunction \
    --zip-file fileb://index.zip
```

See https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/post/Tx1UE9W1NQ0GYII/Publishing-Your-Skill-Code-to-Lambda-via-the-Command-Line-Interface

Answer (score 1):

Upload to AWS from the Lambda console, by creating a new function here: https://console.aws.amazon.com/lambda/home. You can also build your functions and upload to AWS using a tool like [Serverless framework](https://serverless.com/framework/).